# Knex.js .whereILike() on an object

Tags: javascript, express, eloquent, knex.js

Have not found an answer on if this is possible. I am passing an object with filters as keys/values.

ex.

```js
const filters = {
  'id': 12,
  'first_name': john
}
```

```js
function findBy(filter) {
  return db('quotes')
    .where(filter)
    .orderBy('id');
}
```

I am trying to set each where clause to be case insensitive with whereILike(). Does anyone have a solution they can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this:

https://knexjs.org/#Builder-modify

```js
  return db('quotes')
    .modify(function(queryBuilder) {
      if (filter.id) {
        queryBuilder.where('id', filter.id);
      }
      if (filter.first_name) {
        queryBuilder.where('first_name', 'ilike',  `%${filter.first_name}%`);
      }
      if (filter.email) {
        queryBuilder.where('email', 'ilike',  `%${filter.email}%`);
      }
      if (filter.active) {
        queryBuilder.where('is_complete', filter.active);
      }
      if (filter.is_archived) {
        queryBuilder.where('is_archived', filter.is_archived);
      }
    })
    .orderBy('id');
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution if this is the only way knex solves this.